# Keras Custom Layer: __init__takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a layer that will split the columns of a [3,5] tensor into a [3,2] and [3,3] tensor respectively. For example,

```
[[0., 1., 0.,  0., 0.],
 [1., 0., -1., 0., 0.],
 [1., 0., 1.,  1., 0.]]
```

into,

```
[[0., 1.],
 [1., 0.],
 [1., 0.]]

[[0.,  0., 0.],
 [-1., 0., 0.],
 [1.,  1., 0.]]
```

This is the custom layer I've tried to build,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class NodeFeatureSplitter(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NodeFeatureSplitter, self).__init__()
        
    def call(self, x):
        h_feat = x[...,:2]
        x_feat = x[...,-3:]
        
        return h_feat, x_feat
```

However when I call this layer on the following example I get the aforementioned error,

```
x = tf.constant([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],[1., 0., -1., 0., 0.],[1., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])

h_feat, x_feat = NodeFeatureSplitter(x)
print(h_feat)
print(x_feat)
```

> TypeError: __ init __() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Can someone highlight what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks <3

Comment: Layers do not take input values in the constructor (the _ _ init _ _ function).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Could please elaborate on your comment, particularly with this specific problem and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NodeFeatureSplitter` class only receives one argument, `self`:

```
class NodeFeatureSplitter(Layer):
```

But you're providing two, `self` and `x`:

```
h_feat, x_feat = NodeFeatureSplitter(x)
```

You don't want to pass the `x` when defining the layer, but only when calling it:

```
my_layer = NodeFeatureSplitter()
h_feat, x_feat = my_layer(x)  # This is executing __call__, we're using our layer instance as a callable
```

Comment: I realise I should've called NodeFeatureSplitter()(x) instead of what I have above. Thanks for the response and explanation!